# Polygon Pour Neck Width

Tags: pcb, altium

Im using the polygon tool in Circuit Studio (basically Altium Lite). and I am trying to increase the necks which coonnect the pour and pad to maximize connection area. But having a hard time finding it. Does anyone know how to increase the necks or make them cover the whole pad
[image]

Comment: Not familiar with CircuitStudio, but in Altium, you can disable thermals or configure them at Polygon Connect Style: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-nexus/pcb-dlg-polygonconnectstylerule-framepolygon-connect-style-ad?version=2.0

Answer (score 1):

Seems it has the same name as in Altium: **Polygon Connect Style**

In general, the term for them would be "[Thermals](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/38392/what-are-thermals)". Might be interesting to read what they are for before completely removing them.

From Circuit Studio [documentation](http://documentation.circuitstudio.com/display/CSTU/PCB_Dlg-PolygonConnectStyleRule_Frame((Polygon+Connect+Style))_CS):

[image]